# How do I count "NEUTRAL", "POSITIVE", and "NEGATIVE" for each date using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

How do I count "NEUTRAL", "POSITIVE", and "NEGATIVE" for each date? I group date first, then using "value_counts()" but I did not obtain what I expect. Which part of the code I should solve?

```
df01['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df01['date'], dayfirst=True)
df01_sentiment = df01.groupby("date")["new_sentiment"].value_counts()
```

Current output

```
date                 new_sentiment
2020-12-01 08:18:29  NEUTRAL          1
2020-12-01 14:53:17  NEUTRAL          1
2020-12-01 17:29:13  NEUTRAL          1
2020-12-02 17:00:01  NEUTRAL          1
2020-12-02 18:09:52  NEUTRAL          1
                                     ..
2020-12-30 22:19:22  NEUTRAL          2
2020-12-30 22:48:58  NEGATIVE         1
2020-12-31 01:00:00  POSITIVE         1
2020-12-31 03:27:44  NEUTRAL          1
2020-12-31 06:38:52  NEUTRAL          1
```

Expected output

```
date       new_sentiment
2020-12-01   NEUTRAL          3
2020-12-02   NEUTRAL          2
                              ..
2020-12-30  NEUTRAL           2
2020-12-31  POSITIVE          1
2020-12-31  NEUTRAL           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df01_sentiment = df01.groupby(df01["date"].dt.date)["new_sentiment"].value_counts()
```

Or:

```
df01['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df01['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.date
df01_sentiment = df01.groupby("date")["new_sentiment"].value_counts()
```

If need also all datetimes (also if not exist in original `DataFrame`):

```
df01_sentiment = df01.resample('d', on="date")["new_sentiment"].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that the columns is datetime64

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date":["2020-12-01 08:18:29", "2020-12-01 14:53:17", "2020-12-01 17:29:13", "2020-12-02 17:00:01", "2020-12-02 18:09:52"],
    "new_sentiment":["NEUTRAL", "NEUTRAL", "NEGATIVE", "NEUTRAL", "POSITIVE"],
    "unit":[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
})

print(df.dtypes)

date                     object
new_sentiment            object
unit                      int64
dtype: object
```

Column to date type

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

print(df.dtypes)

date             datetime64[ns]
new_sentiment            object
unit                      int64
dtype: object

df

date    new_sentiment   unit
0   2020-12-01  NEUTRAL     1
1   2020-12-01  NEUTRAL     2
2   2020-12-01  NEGATIVE    1
3   2020-12-02  NEUTRAL     1
4   2020-12-02  POSITIVE    1
```

So, if you need to count `new_sentiment`based on date

```
df.groupby("date")["new_sentiment"].value_counts()

date        new_sentiment
2020-12-01  NEUTRAL          2
            NEGATIVE         1
2020-12-02  NEUTRAL          1
            POSITIVE         1
Name: new_sentiment, dtype: int64
```

On the other hand, if you need to count the column `unit`

```
df.groupby(["date", "new_sentiment"])["unit"].sum()

date        new_sentiment
2020-12-01  NEGATIVE         1
            NEUTRAL          3
2020-12-02  NEUTRAL          1
            POSITIVE         1
Name: unit, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

In you current implementation you are trying to group it on the basis of the time as well, that is why in your current output you are getting the count based on the time and not based on the date.

Take for example the first records :

```
date                 new_sentiment
2020-12-01 08:18:29  NEUTRAL          1
```

> There is only one entry with new_sentiment = NEUTRAL at time 2020-12-01 08:18:29 that's why count is 1.

To get the expected count you can change the date format in the date column from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to YYYY-MM-DD and then use the same code to get the counts.